# Java Annotation or Code Generation

Tags: java, annotations, code-generation, java-annotations

Give a nested class definition

```
class A {
   B b;
   public B getB() {
       return b;
   }
}

class B {
   ArrayList<C> list;
   public getListC() {
    return list;
  }
}

class C {
  D d;
  public D getD() {
    return d;
   }
}

class D {
   E e;
   public E getE() {
       return e;
    } 
}
```

Now let's say that I have an Instance of Class A and I want to get access to an instance of E through A's instance like following

```
E someMethod(A a) {
    if (a == null
       || a.getB() == null
       || a.getB().getListC() == null
       || a.getB().getList().isEmpty()
       || a.getB().getList().get(0) == null
       || a.getB().getList().get(0).getD() == null) {
       return null;
     }
    return a.getB().getList().get(0).getD().getE();
}
```

Now I want to know if there is a way to automatically genererate the above  code using Annotation or some other tool so that I don't have to repeaditly write such a code. I should only be doing following

```
E someMethod(A a) {
    @AwesomeAnnotation(a.getB().getList().get(0).getD().getE());
}
```

Comment: whatever the annotation would be (which I am unaware of) the input would cause NullPointerException

Comment: You should consider using Optionnals, it's going to be easier than code generation. Also think about whether or not it make sense for these objects to be null, if not then using defaults value might be a better solution.

Comment: why not simply use a method (or a try/catch)?

Comment: Java has method references, you may want to write a method that do what you want. `getOptional(a,A::getB,B::getC,C::getD,D::getE)`?

Comment: @Derlin catch of NPE is very dangerous, if you were to replace those simple getter one day with some computation, you could break in the computation and swallow the exception silently.

Comment: @user202729 correct me if I am wrong, however, wouldn't Optional require changing the fields declaration of nested types to like  Optional<ClassName>? What if nested classes are part of a thirdparty library  and can't be changed?

Comment: Should you @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope instead? ...

Comment: That's why I suggest KludJe as the answer because it also works for all cases, but if it's your code you should consider Optionnals.

Answer (score 1):

[KludJe](http://kludje.uk/#nulls) is probably what you want.

Comment: Interesting, Minimum is java 8, I will check if that could work

Comment: Also, do you know if this uses runtime reflection?

Comment: No, only using method references (that's why it require Java 8). See here: https://github.com/mcdiae/kludje/blob/master/kludje-core/src/main/java/uk/kludje/Nullifier.java